# Custom drawing in JFrame Doesn't Display

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm designing a strip chart, but it isn't displaying. Its encapsulating JFrame is displaying, and `paintComponent()` is being called, but no gray grid lines are appearing. Why is this?

```
class ChartArea extends JPanel {

        private int Yscl, Xscl;
        private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
        private static final Color LINE_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
        private static final Color GRIDLINE_COLOR = Color.GRAY;

        ChartArea() {
            setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
            setForeground(LINE_COLOR);
            Yscl = 20;
            Xscl = 20;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            int height = getHeight();
            int width = getWidth();
            double max = data.getMax(); //gets the maximum value in the data set

            try {
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));

                //put the origin in the bottom right. Positive is up and left
                g2d.translate(width, height);
                g2d.scale(-1d, -1d);

                //if the data set exceeds the window height, scale it down
                if (max > height) {
                    g2d.scale(1, height / max);
                }
                paintGrid(g2d);
                paintLine(g2d);
            } finally {
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        private void paintGrid(Graphics2D g) {
            g.setPaint(GRIDLINE_COLOR);

            //Vertical Lines
            for (double pos = 0; pos > getWidth(); pos += Xscl) {
                Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(pos, 0d, pos, getHeight());
                g.draw(line);
            }

            //Horizontal Lines
            for (double pos = 0; pos > getHeight(); pos += Yscl) {
                Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(0d, pos, getWidth(), pos);
                g.draw(line);
            }
        }

        private void paintLine(Graphics2D g) {
            g.setPaint(LINE_COLOR);
            Path2D plot2 = new Path2D.Double();

            if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                plot2.moveTo(0.0, data.get(0));
                for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
                    plot2.lineTo((double) i, data.get(i));
                }
                g.draw(plot2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: try simplifying.  is your scaling off?  you translate by w+h, then scale to negtive, then mess with the scale again.  try drawing something before the scale/translate and see if your math assumptions are off there.

Comment: The scale to negative simply flips the axes so that when it's in the bottom right, I don't have to make all my coordinates negative. I'm 99.999% confident that that isn't the problem.

Comment: well, that leaves a 0.001 chance you're wrong :)  have you tried it?

Comment: (and technically there isn't any AWT involved here, is there?  this is all swing)

Comment: @John (pretty much the only swing involved is the JPanel. The rest is all AWT) I messed with the scale and it didn't change anything. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: *kindof*.  You're drawing in a custom swing component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there a typo in `for` loops conditions that draw lines. The loops are never executed with current conditions. If you change the conditions to `pos < getWidth();` and `pos < getHeight();` you should see the grid. Here is a complete method:

```
private void paintGrid(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setPaint(GRIDLINE_COLOR);

    //Vertical Lines
    //for (double pos = 0; pos > getWidth(); pos += Xscl) {
    for (double pos = 0; pos < getWidth(); pos += Xscl) {
        Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(pos, 0d, pos, getHeight());
        g.draw(line);
    }

    //Horizontal Lines
    //for (double pos = 0; pos > getHeight(); pos += Yscl) {
    for (double pos = 0; pos < getHeight(); pos += Yscl) {
        Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(0d, pos, getWidth(), pos);
        g.draw(line);
    }
}
```

Here is a result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding paintComponent to *only* paint your custom panel.  You simply need to paint the parent instance as well.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // custom painting
}
```

Comment: OK, now I'm getting a black background, but no gridlines.

Comment: Make sure you do your gridline painting after the call to `super.paintComponent`.  If the gridlines continue to not draw, there may be an issue in your grid painting code.

Comment: if you're drawing the whole area, you *might* not want to call super, you probably want to fill the background yourself with whatever color you want your graph to be.

Comment: I tried to  draw a rectangle with `Graphics.drawRect(int, int, int, int)` and it only drew a ±2px thick black horizontal line at the top of my JPanel. After adding `super.paintComponent(g);` it worked. @JohnGardner